# How to label streetnames that were convertes from dxf (CAD) in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, cad

i have not yet worked with CAD data in ArcMap so my question is:

I need to display street names from dxf files that were converted to shp. Now I have a large number of shapefiles that were converted from CAD-datasets (in ArcMap 10.1). I want to label the street names fitting to the street-lines. Usually I would simply label the streets by their names by using street address placement style but I dont know how to do that now.

Comment: What format is the data in now? Is it point data with the street name in the attributes?

Comment: Yes, its point data with the street names in the attrubutes. But the attributes are separted, so if a street name contains of two words (e.g. main street) they both have their own attrubute ("main" in one line and "street" in the next line)

Answer (score 1):

create a new field then calculate =[namefield1]&" "&[namefield2]
then label off of the new combined name field.  If you need to associate the points with a line file, then use a spatial join.

Comment: in which attribute table to create a new field?